# Swift 5 CollectionView get indexPath by longPress cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, long-press

I am looking way to get indexPath or data when i do longPress on cell. Basically i can to delete album from collectionView, to do that i need to get **id**.

**My cellForItem**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AlbumCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCollectionViewCell
    cell.data = albumsDataOrigin[indexPath.row]

    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressGetstureDetected))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

    return cell
}
```

**longPressGetstureDetected**

```
@objc func longPressGetstureDetected(){
    self.delegateAlbumView?.longPressGetstureDetected()
}
```

**delete func**

```
func longPressGetstureDetected() {
    showAlertWith(question: "You wanna to delete this album?", success: {

        self.deleteAlbum() //Here i need to pass ID
    }, failed: {
        print("Delete cenceled")
    })
}
```

**For people who looking complete answer**

```
@objc func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: collectionView)
        if let index = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint) {
            self.delegateAlbumView?.longPressGetstureDetected(id: albumsDataOrigin[index.row].id ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the gesture function in the UICollectionVIewCell file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by getting the coordinates of the press using `gesture.location(in:)` Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-location

Then use `indexPathForItem(at:)` to retrieve the IndexPath of the cell touched.  Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618030-indexpathforitem

Based on this you probably do not need a different gesture recognizer for each cell, you can probably register it with the collection view once.

---

Solution provided by George Heints based on the above:

```
@objc func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: collectionView)
        if let index = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint) {
            self.delegateAlbumView?.longPressGetstureDetected(id: albumsDataOrigin[index.row].id ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

I would recommend to use the State.recognized instead of State.began, your mileage may vary!

Comment: I added completed code (UPDATED) thanks to you, can you please add it to your post for people who will need it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

extension UIResponder {

    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next?.next(type)
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
        return next(UICollectionView.self)
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return collectionView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

By the help with this extension you can know the indexPath of collection view from collection view cell file. And you can simply find the id of the photo by the indexPath from data array and delete it.